# How do I determine a user is logged out when using passport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

Started learning Node today and I am almost positive my user is not being logged out correctly and I do not understand why. To login the user I've written the following code in my routes file

```
app.post('/api/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, res, req) {
  console.log(res);
}));
```

then in another file this code to handle the logic of logging in my user

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("serializeUser");
  console.log(user);
     done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log("deserializeUser");
  console.log(id);
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(
  {
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, username, password, done) {
    console.log(req.sessionID);
    process.nextTick(function() {
      User.findOne({ 'local.username': username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (user) {
          return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', "Username already taken"));
        } else {
          let newUser = new User();
          newUser.local.username = username;
          newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

          newUser.save( function(saveErr) {
            if (saveErr) {
              throw saveErr;
            }
            return done(null, newUser);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  })
);
```

Then to logout my user I wrote the following code in my routes file

```
app.get('/api/session', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.sessionID);
  req.logOut();
  console.log(req.sessionID);
});
```

A few things confuse me about this code.

1. To my understanding `serializeUser` is suppose to change the `user.id` to bits and store it in the cookies but the `console.log` never prints which leads me to think that this code never runs, why? I read that `req.login()` is implicitly called so I should not need to worry about it.
2. The `console.log` which is inside the callback of `LocalStrategy` prints a sessionID. When is this set if I haven't created my new user yet or the `console.log` mentioned in point 1 never runs?
3. Inside of logout I call `req.logOut()` with a `console.log(req.sessionID)` before and after `req.logOut()` and these both print the same thing. I'm assuming these sessionID's are what the cookies use to determine a session is valid, if so, does this mean the user never logs out as the sessionID is never changed?

Thanks